# Make a unique form for each individual user

Tags: django, django-forms

I need to make a unique form for each individual user but I'm not exactly sure how. My thought process is to have a list of possible fields and an admin checks the boxes on whether or not he wants the field to show up in the rendered form. When the form is rendered it could pull the list of fields the user is able to see and render a form based on that list. Is this possible or do I need to make a form for each user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out by using this in forms.py. I was trying to add on to the form widget to all my fields in the form but it was causing all forms to be rendered so I instead used widget-tweaks in the html to get my desired render.

```
class myForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = myModel
        myList = ['field1']
        fields = myList
```